# Sort 2 lists in Python based on the ratio of individual corresponding elements or based on a third list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, lambda

I am trying to write different implementations for a fractional [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

For this I have 2 arrays:

1. Values
2. Weights

The elements value[n] corresponds to element weights[n]. So we can calculate value_per_unit as:

```
for I in range(values):
    value_per_unit.append(values[I]/weights[I])
value_per_unit.sort()
```

I now **need the 2 arrays (values and weights) to be sorted according to the value_per_unit array**

eg:
If

- values = [60, 100, 120]
- weights = [20, 50, 30]

Then

- values_per_unit = [3.0, 2.0, 4.0]
- and so values_per_unit_sorted will be [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]

I need the values and weights arrays to become:

- values_sorted = [100,60,120]
- weights_sorted = [50,20,30]

Is there a way to achieve this using simple lambda functions?

I can still do something like this, but it seems highly inefficient every-time I need to access the elements:

```
weights[(value_per_unit_sorted.index(max(value_per_unit_sorted)))]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In one line:

```
values, weights = zip(*sorted(zip(values, weights), key=lambda t: t[0]/t[1]))
```

---

To explain: First, zip the lists to pair them.

```
pairs = zip(values, weights) 
# [(60, 20), (100, 50), (120, 30)]
```

Then, sort by the quotient of value to weight.

```
sorted_pairs = sorted(pairs, key=lambda t: t[0]/t[1]) 
# [(100, 50), (60, 20), (120, 30)]
```

Finally, unzip them back into separate lists.

```
values, weights = zip(*sorted_pairs)
# (100, 60, 120), (50, 20, 30)
```

---

An alternative is to construct tuples explicitly containing the ratio as the first element.

```
ratios, values, weights = zip(*sorted((v/w, v, w) for v, w in zip(values, weights)))
```

The former appears to be slightly faster in some quick testing. If you're looking for an optimal algorithm, you're probably going to have to unroll things and the solution will not be as concise.

And to address the comment from @TomWyllie, if you already have the list of ratios, you can use:

```
ratios, values, weights = zip(*sorted(zip(ratios, values, weights)))
```

Note that these last two solutions differ from the initial solution in the case where two pairs have an equal ratio. These solutions will sort secondarily by value, while the first solution will keep the items in the same order as the original list.

Comment: Quite a small issue, but you're recalculating all the ratios with this solution, OP has highlighted in bold now that it should be sorted "*according to the value_per_unit array*", which I'm fairly sure means to use the "array" (list) and not recalculate the values. Good answer though :)

Comment: @Tom Then the second solution can be used and OP can skip constructing the list of ratios in the first place.

Comment: I agree that's probably sensible, but OP hasn't asked to skip the step of constructing the ratios; it's entirely possible he might need that `list` for something else anyway, and so wants a solution that avoids the recalculation.

Comment: @TomWyllie That makes things simpler, I've added a find solution for that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For a more explicit (but arguably less pythonic) solution, create a list of indices, *sorted by the value at that index in* `value_per_unit`, and reorder `values` and `weights` accordingly.

```
sorted_indices = [index for index, value in 
                  sorted(enumerate(value_per_unit), key=lambda x: x[1])]
values = [values[i] for i in sorted_indices]
weights = [weights[i] for i in sorted_indices]

print(values, weights)
```

Outputs:

```
([100, 60, 120], [50, 20, 30])
```

You can tidy this up, eliminating the unnecessary extra loops using `zip`, and with a generator expression;

```
values, weights = zip(*((values[i], weights[i]) for i, value in
                  sorted(enumerate(value_per_unit), key=lambda x: x[1])))
print(values)
print(weights)
```

Which outputs;

```
(100, 60, 120)
(50, 20, 30)
```

Note these final values are `tuples` not `lists`. If you really need the output to be a list, a simple `values, weights = map(list, (values, weights))` should suffice. You could even wrap that into the one liner, although by that point it's probably getting pretty hard to follow what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to do this is to make a multi-dimensional list with the values and weights:

```
for i in range(len(values)):
    values_and_weights.append([values[i], weights[i])
# The resulting list is [[60, 20], [100, 50], [120, 30]]
```

Then, use the sort method with a value divided by weight as the key.

```
values_and_weights.sort(key=(lambda x: x[0]/x[1]))
```

Comment: The first part can be simplified by using `zip` and then reduces to my second suggestion.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Great minds think alike! My reasoning for doing it this way is that it is more explicit and it's more obvious what's going on.

Comment: I'd argue that using the built-in function `zip` is more Pythonic, but to each their own.

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are having is cause by using a calculated field over each element (element I will have the calculated value `values[I]/weights[I]`).
To solve this and still keep it extremely easy to understand, you can turn it into a tuple of this form: `( calculated_value, (value, weight) )`, per element.

This approach keeps it easy to read and understand. Look at the following solution:

```
values = [60, 100, 120]
weights = [20, 50, 30]
value_per_unit = []

for I in range(len(values)):
    value_per_unit.append( (values[I]/weights[I], (values[I], weights[I])) )
sorted_value_per_unit = sorted(value_per_unit, key=lambda x: x[0])

sorted_values = []
sorted_weights = []
for I in range(len(values)):
    (value, weight) = sorted_value_per_unit[I][1]
    sorted_values.append(value)
    sorted_weights.append(weight)

print(str(sorted_values))
print(str(sorted_weights))
```

Also, note that I modified the loop from your original code:

`range(values)` was change to `range(len(values))`

Since range would need the length of the list, rather than the list itself.